# Understanding ID3D11Device and ID3D11DeviceContext

Tags: c++, directx-11

I have some problems understanding the difference between `ID3D11Device` and `ID3D11DeviceContext`.

- Is the `ID3D11Device` a representative of your GPU and `ID3D11DeviceContext` used for functions, to control the `device`?
- Why do you need 2 objects?
- Which function do you use with the device and which with the device object?
- Which object sends the final image to the backbuffer?
- The back buffer is in the `ID3D11RenderTargetView` object, isn't it?
- Which objects are connected to the swap chain, and why?

Comment: Different lifetimes.  You'll have to co-operate with other programs that want to use the device, you can get D3DERR_DEVICELOST if one steals it away from you.  Like the user Alt+Tabbing to another game.  Keeps the device valid but you have to recreate the device context.  Ask only one question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `ID3D11Device` is used for **creating** resources, for example, the many shaders in the pipeline.

The `ID3D11DeviceContext` is used for **binding** those resources to the pipeline, for example, the many shaders.

```
device->CreatePixelShader(/*arguments*/);
context->PSSetShader(/*pass shader created with 'device'*/);
```

> But why you need then two objects?

So that you don't have 1 "God" object that does everything (that's a guess `:)`).

> Which object send the final Image to the backbuffer.

The `ID3D11DeviceContext` does. I guess with "Image" you mean a texture, if yes, the image doesn't get "sent", it gets copied to the back buffer, using the method `Draw`.

> The backbuffer is in the ID3D11RenderTargetView object, isn't it?

Yes, in form of a `ID3D11Resource`, which would be the back buffer "texture" (The `Draw` calls draw into that "texture").

> And which objects are connect with the SwapChain and why exactly?

That's a bit broad. The swap chain stores the back buffer textures, and many other informations such as how to flip the buffers, which window is associated with it, ... This gets used when you `Draw` something.

So, I guess the `ID3D11Resource`s are "conntected" with the swap chain, as they store the back buffer textures used by it.

Answer (score 1):

```
                  ID3D11Device              ID3D11DeviceContext
Purpose:            FACTORY                   STATE of pipeline
Multithreaded:      YES                       NO
Amount basic:       one                       one
Amount common:      one                       many
Amount rare:        many                      many
```