# When to use prefix "I" for STRUCTS, classes in directx11?

Tags: c++, class, struct, com, directx

I'm having difficulty understanding when to include the prefix "I" for directx11 STRUCTS and COM object classes?

for example:

1) IDXGI vs DXGI
2) ID3D11 vs D3D11

I can't seem to figure it out when to use what, please help.

Comment: why the heck im getting down vote(s)?  there is another very similar(not exact) question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37509559/understanding-id3d11device-and-id3d11devicecontext   and they did not get an downvotes...

Comment: read again the good way to ask a question http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I or not I in a class name is a pure opinion based decision, I means interface,and cary the predicate it will be a complex object that provide a service without providing the knowledge of the internal. A simple struct with basic members is not an  interface, that is all.

Answer (score 1):

DirectX interfaces make use of the Component Object Model (COM).

Not all aspects of COM are used for DirectX, but it follows the conventions of using "I" to indicate interfaces, interfaces are derived from `IUnknown` which handles reference counting and 'casting' of interfaces through `QueryInterface`, and interfaces are designed to map directly to C++ abstract virtual classes.

The DirectX flavor of COM is often informally called 'COM lite'. The main difference is that the lifetime of any 'child' object created from a device are immediately invalid when the device object is destroyed. Also 'set' objects do not have their reference counts incremented by just binding them to the rendering pipeline.

See [The Component Object Model](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms694363.aspx)

You should strongly consider making use of the [ComPtr](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/ComPtr) smart-pointer for working with Direct3D interfaces. It makes life a lot easier.

> BTW you might want to take some time to read through [DirectX Tool Kit tutorials](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/Getting-Started) which covers much of the basics of Direct3D.